# Extract data from Chatfuel

Tags: json, api, chatfuel

I have created chat bot using Chatfuel and I want to extract the data as name, email, number which is asked while chating. I store this information in variables. The only thing is that I want to Fetch the values in the variables to my website. 
There they have given option for JSON API, but I am not able to use JSON API. How should I use this JSON API to fetch the data to my website ?

Comment: Flagged as **too broad**.

Answer (score 1):

I manage to store some of the user attributes to my own database using JSON API. I am using Amazon Web Services to build my backend. I pass to all my endpoints as query parameters the desired user attributes. I found this as the easiest way.Bare in mind that you can use user attributes ({{user_attribute}}) in JSON API url.

Answer (score 0):

We have the same issue that I have encountered just yesterday.
I follow every forum chat fuel had and found out these solutions for you, depending on your requirement:

1. To pass it via URL like **website.com?param1=100&param2=200**. Please refer to this link: https://community.chatfuel.com/t/how-do-i-create-a-button-with-a-simple-text-in-json-postback/555/2
2. Use third-party JSON API hosted on herokuapp (free app hosting) running on NodeJS following this link:
   https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-nodejs#introduction